# Visualforce page not displaying query data

Tags: visualforce, soql, custom-controller

I am having an issue where the query results are not displaying in my vf page.  I've gone as far as temporarily assigning a specific id so that I know that I get a return value from my query.  I don't understand why nothing is displayed on the page.

Controller:

```
public class ReviewAccountCovenants {

public String currentRecordID= '001j000000VgiQN';
public LLC_BI__Review__c Review                 {get;set;}
public Loan_Memo__c myMemo                      {get;set;}
public list<LLC_BI__Covenant2__c> relatedcovs   {get;set;}
public void GatherCovenants(){   
    list<LLC_BI__Covenant2__c> relatedcovs =  [
    SELECT Id, Requirement__c, Actual__c, LLC_BI__Covenant_Type__c, Name 
    FROM LLC_BI__Covenant2__c
    WHERE Id in (
            SELECT LLC_BI__Covenant2__c
            FROM LLC_BI__Account_Covenant__c
            WHERE LLC_BI__Account__c  =: currentRecordID)]; 

    system.debug(relatedcovs);

    }
    }
```

VF Page

```
<apex:form >
    <div>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="covenant" value="{!relatedcovs}"  >   
                <apex:column headerValue="Covenant Type">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!covenant.LLC_BI__Covenant_Type__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Requirement">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!covenant.Requirement__c}" />
                </apex:column>      
                <apex:column headerValue="Actual">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!covenant.Actual__c}" />
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your query into a function that's never called. Instead, you can just change it to a constructor, and drop the local variables.

```
public class ReviewAccountCovenants {

    public String currentRecordID= '001j000000VgiQN';
    public LLC_BI__Review__c Review                 {get;set;}
    public Loan_Memo__c myMemo                      {get;set;}
    public list<LLC_BI__Covenant2__c> relatedcovs   {get;set;}
    public ReviewAccountCovenants(){   // Constructors have no return type
        // Use the class level member relatedcovs
        relatedcovs =  [SELECT Id, Requirement__c, Actual__c, LLC_BI__Covenant_Type__c, Name 
                        FROM LLC_BI__Covenant2__c
                        WHERE Id in (
                            SELECT LLC_BI__Covenant2__c
                            FROM LLC_BI__Account_Covenant__c
                            WHERE LLC_BI__Account__c  =: currentRecordID)]; 
    }
}
```